# Searching a Mongo database using PyMongo, while using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, pymongo

I currently have a PyMongo collection with around 100,000 documents. I need to perform a regex search on each of these documents, checking each document against around 1,800 values to see if a particular field (which is an array) contains one of the 1,800 strings. After testing a variety of ways of using regex, such as compiling into a regular expression, multiprocessing and multi-threading, the performance is still abysmal, and takes around 30-45 minutes.

The current regex I'm using to find the value at the end of the string is:

```
rgx = re.compile(string_To_Be_Compared + '$')
```

And then this is ran using a standard pymongo find query:

```
coll.find( { 'field' : rgx } )
```

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for querying these values in a more optimal way? Ideally the search to return all the values should take less than 5 minutes. Would the best course of action to be use something like ElasticSearch or am I missing something basic?

Thanks for you time

Comment: Can you give some more examples, please, around what your data looks like and, more importantly, what your `string_To_Be_Compared` pattern needs to support.

Comment: @dnickless the data is in the form: { '_id', '-', 'id' : 'CVE-103-333', 'vulnerable_configuration' : 'cpe:a:python:python:3.4'} and my text i would have to search for would be something like 'python:3.4', and the $ is appended to ensure it matches the end of the string

Comment: So do you need substring matching or do you just want to find full matches? Also, where is the array in your sample data?

Comment: I need a substring match, and sometimes the 'vulnerabile_configurations' field is an array, and sometimes it will be a single string,

Comment: I would try creating an index on the `vulnerable_configuration` field (the regex can scan it instead of scanning the entire collection so that might help). Also, you could attempt to construct a majorly big single query (no more than 16MB, though) that contains all your conditions and then throw it at MongoDB in one go as opposed to running lots of individual queries.

Comment: @dnickless yeah i thought about that as well, and when i tried both those methods they still were very slow, due to the number of values that had to be compared. Is this just one of these things i'll just have to accept?

Comment: I certainly think there's room for improvement 100k docs is not a lot and 45 minutes sounds like you'd be faster checking the documents manually. Let's see if there's other ideas popping up.

Comment: Have you in anyway tried using the `$regex` query operator? What is `rgx`?

Comment: @oluwafemi I have used $regex as well, and it is still very slow. I also tried a large or query with all the values as $regex queries and it was still very slow. Rgx is just a variable name to compile a regex variable from the re library

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47801187/edit)  your question to add sample document and the expected result. What `mongod` version are you running on?